# const reference in range-based-for-loop not working

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, ranged-loops

I thought that you could use a const reference in ranged-based-for-loops in C++11, But when I compile this code using g++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::string, int> > coordinates {
        {{"x", 50}, {"y", 50}},
        {{"x", 25}, {"y", 75}},
        {{"x", 326}, {"y", 412}},
    };
    for(const auto& i : coordinates) {
        std::cout << "{\"x\" : " << i["x"] << ", \"y\" : " << i["y"] << "}\n";
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
const_error.cc:13:38: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const
      std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int,
      std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      int> > >'
        std::cout << "{\"x\" : " << i["x"] << ", \"y\" : " << i["y"] << "}\n";
                                    ~^~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_map:1131:18: note: 
      candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int,
      std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      int> > >', but method is not marked const
    mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& __k);
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_map:1133:18: note: 
      candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int,
      std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      int> > >', but method is not marked const
    mapped_type& operator[](key_type&& __k);
                 ^
const_error.cc:13:64: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const
      std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int,
      std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      int> > >'
        std::cout << "{\"x\" : " << i["x"] << ", \"y\" : " << i["y"] << "}\n";
                                                              ~^~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_map:1131:18: note: 
      candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int,
      std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      int> > >', but method is not marked const
    mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& __k);
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_map:1133:18: note: 
      candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int,
      std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      int> > >', but method is not marked const
    mapped_type& operator[](key_type&& __k);
                 ^
```

But when I remove the `const` from the range-based for loop, It works just fine. Why won't my code compile fine with the const reference?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with for loops. You could have narrowed this down far more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator[]` isn't const. If the key doesn't, exist it adds a value object to that key.

Use [`unordered_map::at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/at/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

The `[]` operator of `map` and `unordered_map` requires being called on a non-const object, because it will update the object to insert a new entry if one did not exist for that key.

What do you want to happen if `"x"` is not in the map for example?

- Create a new entry? Then you can't use `const`.
- Generate a runtime error? Then use `find` or some other function that looks up the map without potentially modifying it, instead of `[]`.